# Creating a matrix with m + 1 columns and n + 1 rows

Tags: python

Any help on how to create a matrix with M + 1 columns and N + 1 rows where M and N  are correspond to the size of the sequences. I need it for alignment of two sequences.

I've tried using numpy. But i got fixed size matrix.

Comment: Perhaps an example?  As presented, this question is pretty self evident (2 dimensional list), but maybe you have a more nuanced case in reality.

Comment: just numpy, but i got fixed size matrix.

Comment: what is wrong with `numpy` and fixed size matrixes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[[0. for i in range(m+1)] for j in range(n+1)]
```

will produce a m+1 by n+1 matrix.

Using a `numpy` `array` will likely be faster for many operations, if you use `numpy` right:

```
numpy.zeros((m+1, n+1))
```